# Связи в базе данных(бд)

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаю впервые бд, подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать такую штуку, чтобы в сущности "запись на приём" время можно было написать не какое попадёт, а в ограничении на расписание врача. заранее спасибо

Comment: я бы пересмотрел схему данных и изменил отношения между сущностями Расписание и Врач, убрал бы связь между Врачом и Записью на приём и добавил связь между Записью и расписанием

Comment: ну а так вообще это можно решить с помощью `CHECK CONSTRAINT`

Answer (score 3):

Я вижу множество мелочей в схеме, которые кажутся мне нелогичными. Подумайте над своей структурой и решите, возможно я прав:

- ID_участка и №_участка не может являться признаком врача, т.к. один врач может работать сразу на нескольких участках (совместительством заниматься), может менять участки. То же и с отделением. Признак врача - только специальность, и то не факт, возможно, некоторые врачи могут совмещать работу по нескольким специальностям.
- Как следствие, сущность участка можно выделить отдельно, и посмотреть - возможно, расписание должно быть привязано к участку, но включить в него также и ссылку на врача, чтобы было понятно, в какой конкретно день какой врач дежурит на этом участке.
- Запись на прием логично привязать к расписанию - запись в расписании - это период, когда участок "открыт", запись должна в этот период попадать. Ссылки на врача при этом не нужно - т.к. она уже есть в расписании. Нужна ссылка на пациента и время приема.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно повесить триггер, который при вставке будет проверять соответствие расписанию.

P.S Не используй русские буквы в названиях атрибутов и сущностей.

Крайне неудобно постоянно переключаться с одной раскладки на другую при написании запросов...